# How to switch JPanels from different classes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have three classes one JFrame class and two JPanel classes. I have added the intial JPanel to the JFrame like so

```
 public JFrame() {

    add(new 1stPanel(this));


    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(null);
}
```

Then i want to use an actionlistener on a button in the 1st panel to remove it and add the other panel which is in another class. I tried giving each class a variable and using the simple remove() and add() like this:

```
private 1stpanel 1p;
private 2ndpanel 2p;

btn.addActionListener((new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
            {
            remove(1p);
            add(2p);
            validate();
            repaint();
            }
        }));
```

that doesn't work i have also tried using JFrame.remove(1p) but that doesn't work either. When i do removeAll() it gets rid of everything in the 1stpanel JPanel but then i can't add the 2ndpanel. 
What code can i use to take out the 1st panel or 1stpanel class and add the 2nd panel which is in another class.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Try to all these operations on `yourframe.getContentPane()`

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  Don't do that.  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `CardLayout` and swap cards (panels).

Could be you problem is the creation `add(new 1stPanel(this))`. You add a local variable but then use fields of class.

Answer (score 2):

your code lines

```
        remove(1p);
        add(2p);
        validate();
        repaint();
```

which you are calling inside the action listener are being called on the this object which I suspect is the JPanel itself. If it is so define a method in the class that is extending the JFrame, place these codes inside that method, and on action event call that method.

Comment: Just tried this

     `public void switchpanels(){
        remove(1p);
        add(2p);
        validate();
        repaint();
   }
       btn.addActionListener((new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
    {
    switchpanels();
    
    }
      }));`

Comment: What was the result. By the way the switchpanels() method needs to be in the class which extends the JFrame.

Comment: Oh ok i'll put the switch panel method in and see what happens

Comment: It asks to put the switch panel method in the 1stpanel class

Comment: The `setLayout(null);` works fine i just need to know how what code to put into the actionListener to get rid of the 1stpanel and add the 2ndpanel.